# Eclipse not responding (Windows 8)

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-8

Eclipse freezes and says "not responding" very often. At first it only happened rarely but now it happens every time I try to edit something. It has become impossible for me to work like this.

About my laptop:

- Intel I5-3230M 2.6GHz
- 8GB RAM
- Windows 8 Professional 64bit

It mostly happens when I try to edit XML. I suddenly can't click anything, then "not responding" window appears and then Eclipse completely crashes. It happens so often that I can't even work anymore.

Screenshot of the error that I get, when it crashes:
[image]

Comment: Try to uninstall by completely removing all files including caches in the AppData folder.

Comment: How are Eclipse files called in AppData? Can't find anything

Comment: Nope AppData is not Eclipse folder but its a windows Application Data folder it contains all the necessary files such as Templates, user files including some apps. get there, find the android SDK file if there is any. but i cannot 100% assume where you have installed the Eclipse and SDK or how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was due to a corrupt workspace.Please check this [link](http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

- Go to your eclipse folder
- Open eclipse.ini in notepad
- Go to this line `launcher.XXMaxPermSize` modify 512M and set 256M
- Do it for both 512M lines
- Save eclipse.ini file and then open Eclipse again.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. I'll try it now and accept your answer if it doesn't crash within an hour or so